# Calling method parent class of extension parent class in SilverStripe

Tags: silverstripe

I am working on a SilverStripe project. What I am trying to do now is that I am trying to call the method of parent class of the extension class.

I have a class like this

```
Order extension GenericOrder {
   public function validate()
   {
      $result = parent::validate(); 
      //Some other code
   }
}
```

Then I created an extension class for it

```
class OrderExtension extends DataExtension
{
    public function validate()
    {
        //here I want to call the validate method of the GenericOrder class
    }
}
```

As you can see in the comment, I am trying to call the validate method of the GenericOrder class which is the parent of Order class which my extension class, OrderExtension class trying to extend. How can I call it?

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->owner->validate();
```

Comment: $this->owner is the class that I am extending.